# Solving $x^3-y^3=xy+61$ in integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

$$x^3-y^3=xy+61$$

I got:

$$(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=xy+61$$

But I can't go any further. I am looking for a solution in integers.

I need some hints to proceed, please!

Comment: I found one solution by inspection: if $x-y=1$, you have $x^2+y^2=61$, which has $x=5,y=6$ as a solution.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Oh, I didn't think of that. Is there a way to solve it? And are those the only answers?

Comment: @Gigili: Given that there are two unknowns, and only one equation, how many answers do you suppose there would be?

Comment: @Joel: There may be only finitely many solutions in integers.

Comment: If $x-y\geq 1$, it follows that$(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=(x-y)xy+(x-y)(x^2+y^2) \geq xy + (x^2+y^2)$ and this allows us to bound the search space within the integers. Looking for such bounds, however crude, is one technique for dealing with this kind of question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Ah, True. I overlooked the word "integer" in OP's question for some odd reason.

Comment: Maybe set $y=x-k$ and solve the resulting quadratic in $x$ for various $k$? Then see which values of $k$ result in integer solutions. The solutions in the reals would be (assuming I didn't make a mistake): $\frac{k(1-3k) \pm \sqrt{(1-3k)(k^3+k^2-244)}}{2(3k-1)}$.

Comment: I made a mistake above. The $k(1-3k)$ term should be $k(3k-1)$.

Comment: @Gigili Adding to Mark Bennet suggestion, once you get some bounds you can restrict your sample space by arguments based on parity/modular arguments. For instance, in the current problem a simple parity argument gives us that both $x$ and $y$ cannot be even. Similarly, if both are odd, then one has to be $1 \bmod 4$ and the other has to be $3 \bmod 4$. Which with some further arguments give us that both cannot be odd. Hence, you can always conclude that one has to be even and other has to be odd.

Comment: The value 
under the square root can only be positive when $k=1,...,5$.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Put $x+y=:u$, $x-y=:v$; then $u$ and $v$ are integers of the same parity. In the new variables the equation becomes
$${1\over8}(6u^2v+2v^3)={1\over4}(u^2-v^2)+61\ ,$$
which can be written as
$$27 u^2+(3v+2)^2={6584\over3 v-1}\ .$$
It follows that $v>1$ and that $3v-1$ must divide $6584=8\cdot 823$; whence  $v\in\{1,3,549,2195\}$. $549$ and $2195$ are obviously too large, and $v:=3$ leeds to $u^2=26$ which has no integer solutions. It remains $v=1$ which leads to $u^2=121$ or $u=\pm11$. Therefore we only have the two solutions $(x_1,y_1):=(6,5)$ and $(x_2,y_2):=(-5,-6)$.

Answer (score 11):

I believe the only answers in the integers are $(6,5)$ and $(-5,-6)$.

If $x$ and $y$ are integers, then we can let $y=x-k$, where $k$ is an integer. Then the equation can be written as a quadratic in $x$:
$$k(x^2+x(x-k)+(x-k)^2)-x(x-k)-61 = 0$$
The solutions to this are:
$$x = \frac{k(3k-1) \pm\sqrt{(1-3k)(k^3+k^2-244)}}{2(3k-1)}$$
The term under the square root is only positive for $k=1,2,3,4,5$, and checking the results for each of these shows that only $k=1$ results in integer solutions (listed above).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how did you get that the term under the square root is only positive for $K=1, \dots, 5$?

Comment: It is a quartic polynomial in $k$ with leading coefficient $-1$.

Comment: Oops, I meant $-3$. The $k^3+k^2-244$ term is increasing in $k$ and is positive when $k \geq 6$, negative when $k \leq 5$. Similarly, the $1-3k$ term is positive for $k\leq 0$, negative for $k\geq 1$. The only integers for which the product is non-negative are $1,...,5$.

Answer (score 8):

If we restrict ourselves to positive solutions, we can do it by brute force. In that case clearly $x>y>0$.

If $x-y=1$, we have $x^2+y^2=61$, which has the unique solution $x=6,y=5$.

If $x-y=2$, we have $2(x^2+xy+y^2)=xy+61$, or $2(x^2+y^2)+xy=61$; clearly $x$ and $y$ must both be odd, with $x^2+y^2<30$. The only candidate is $x=3,y=1$, which clearly doesn't work.

If $x-y=3$, we have $3(x^2+y^2)+2xy=61$; here $x$ and $y$ must have opposite parity, with $x^2+y^2<20$, so $x=4,y=1$ is the only candidate, and it doesn't (quite) work.

If $x-y=4$, we have $4(x^2+y^2)+3xy=61$, so $x$ and $y$ must be odd, and $x^2+y^2<15$; there are no solutions in this case.

Suppose that $x-y\ge 4$. Then $(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)\ge 4(5^2+5\cdot1+1^2)>61$, so there are no solutions.

Comment: Dear Brian, if we draw $x^3-y^3=z$ and $xy+61=z$ just for examining the functions, they intersect eachother infinitely.