# Diophantine problem: Find all pairs of $(x, y)$ such that $x^3-4xy+y^3=-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Find all pairs of integers $x, y$ such that:
> $$x^3-4xy+y^3=-1$$

My analysis:

1. $x$ and $y$ can't be both negative because all terms would be negative and $(x,y)=(-1,-1) \implies (-1)^3-4(-1)(-1)+(-1)^3 =-6 $ would already be too small.
2. Reducing modulo $4$ gives: $x^3+y^3\equiv 3  \pmod 4
   \implies (x,y)\equiv(0,3)$ or $(3,0) \pmod 4$
3. WLOG let $x$ be the larger (+ve) one in a solution pair$\implies x\ge y+1$:

   $-1 = x^3-4xy+y^3 \ge (y+1)^3 - 4(y+1)y +y^3$

   $-2 \ge 2y^3 - y^2 -y$

   $-2 \ge (y-1)(2y^2 + y)$

   Since $(2y^2+y)\ge 0$ and $y\le-1$

Indeed $(x,y)=(0,-1)$ is a solution fitting all the above (inconclusive) results. However, I don't know how to find a lower bound for $y$ to lock down all possible pairs of $(x,y).$ What's the missing step? Am I completely off?

Comment: Note that in 3), in order for $ - 4xy \geq -4(y+1)y$, you are assuming that $ y \leq 0 $ which need not be true as yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** A messy quadratic is better than a simple cubic while dealing with integers.
$$x+y=s\implies x^3-4x(s-x)+(s-x)^3=-1 $$

> Simplifying, $$ (3s+4)x^2-(3s^2+4s)x+s^3+1=0$$

> The discriminant must be non-negative, $$\Delta=-(3s+4)(s^3-4s^2+4)\ge 0$$

> If $s\in (-\infty,-2]$ or $s\in [4,\infty)$, $\Delta<0$. Therefore, $s\in\{-1,2,3\}$. Only $s=-1$ results in an integer value for $x$.

> $$(x,y)\in \{(-1,0),(0,-1)\}$$

Comment: Wow. That's a clever (and non-trivial) solution! Is it a general trick to reduce the max power of one of the variable to solve it this way? Also, how do you figure out the roots to that s^3-4s^2+4 part by hand in a contest?

Comment: Yes it can be useful to convert higher order equations to quadratics. [This well known problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139785/solving-x3-y3-xy61-in-integers) can be solved with a similar idea.

Comment: You don't need to find the exact roots of the cubic, you can just plug in integers to check when it will be positive and negative. After a point, the $s^3$ term will start dominating.